# Eclipse(Android SDK) is showing the error "content not allowed in prolog "

Tags: android, file, manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/sudoku111"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".sudokugame1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/about_title"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Prefs"
        android:label="@string/settings_title" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Game"
        android:label="@string/game_title" />
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

this program is showing "content not allowed in prolog" error on 2nd line.....I've tried many times and many ways to eliminate this....but couldn't do so.....can anyone tell me the solution